# How can I tell if the built-in flash on my dSLR is broken beyond self-repair?

Tags: nikon, flash, dslr, repair

My built-in flash D50 is broken. It is popping up, but it isn't flashing. It fell down, so is it broken, or can I still fix it?

Comment: Did it stop working immediately after the fall? I'd say "check with Nikon tech support", but they'll undoubtedly say to send it in to be checked.

Comment: which part of "nu user serviceable parts inside" didn't you understand :)

Comment: @jwenting you misspelled "nü"

Answer (score 11):

**Unless you're a camera technician, it's broken beyond self-repair.**

Don't mess around with flashes if you're not skilled with high-voltage electronics and camera internals. Flashes need to store charges of 300V or so in order to work, and may not discharge all the way when you turn the camera off. If you open up your camera and touch the wrong thing, you'll get a nasty shock, and could end up dead.

If the risk of death isn't enough to scare you, add in the risk of frying or otherwise breaking the rest of your precious camera. I'd really recommend taking/sending it to a repair shop. Chances are, you'll need to replace some parts, and a shop will either have them on hand or be able to get them quickly.

Comment: "If the risk of death isn't enough to scare you, add in the risk of frying or otherwise breaking the rest of your precious camera" How to tell when a hobby is starting to get a bit *too* serious.

Comment: Hi so the warranty wil fix my slr . will it be fixed? :(

Comment: If you have a 3rd party accident warranty, then yes. However, it's unlikely that the manufacturer warranty will cover damage from an accident. I'd recommend calling Nikon support.

Comment: @JariKeinänen nobody remembers a coward!

Comment: Messing with open high voltage gear is courage. Messing with hard to disassemble and potentially charged high voltage gear that tends to come apart in unexpected ways and drop live parts into your hands is foolhardy. The latter tends to describe the construction of most flashguns and flash equipped cameras.