# How can I fix the flash in a Nikon D80 camera?

Tags: diy, repair, popup-flash

How do I remove and replace the built-in flash in a Nikon D80?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if the built-in flash on my dSLR is broken beyond self-repair?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/how-can-i-tell-if-the-built-in-flash-on-my-dslr-is-broken-beyond-self-repair)

Comment: Best to discharge the capacitor before poking around. Usually under the left grip. You can use a resistor (2k ohm 5w) or use a volt meter to bleed it down. The chances of it killing a healthy adult are very remote indeed. And don't forget to remove the battery first.

Comment: Killing, maybe. Injuring, no. Startling you enough to hurt yourself by falling or  losing control of tools, not unlikely at all.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to take it to a certified nikon repair center to have it checked out, if it's under warranty. Otherwise seek out a camera repair person who can service it for you.

See this [related question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/how-can-i-tell-if-the-built-in-flash-on-my-dslr-is-broken-beyond-self-repair) for why attempting to fix your pop-up flash is a bad idea. To summarize: you could seriously injure or kill yourself if you try.

Comment: To put the danger into some perspective: a cardiac defibrillator uses the same circuitry as a xenon photoflash -- same high-voltage generator, same capacitors, same regulating circuits (well, except that they're designed to fail safe) -- except that you take the place of the flash tube in the circuit (and the method of initiating the discharge is different). While the pop-up may not have 400 joules ready and waiting (as, say, a studio strobe easily might) it *can* trigger an arrhythmia or a fibrillation.

Comment: I once took apart disposable camera after removing the film just to mess around. As soon as it was open, I accidentally touched a circuit near the flash and my right arm was instantly numb. I was lucky.