# Can I repair a cracked internal flash in a Nikon D7000?

Tags: flash, nikon-d7000, repair, diy, popup-flash

During our latest holidays unfortunately we dropped our d7000 and the internal flash broke (the plastic and the bulb are both cracked). Is this something I could replace myself? If so, where can I find the part?

Comment: You said it is cracked, but it is still flashing?

Comment: @Gapton, nope, it is not flashing. You can actually hear pieces of the bulb if you shake the camera.

Comment: I think camera flash, which connects to a capacitor, is rather dangerous to fix on your own if you are not familiar with electronics and the safety precautions. It is not likely that you would, but if the capacitor is triggered by accident you could be sent to a hospital. Its worth knowing what accidents could happend before you attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a little for you on Google, seems a few people have encountered this and they did replace the bulb on their own. I would caution that they had a different model but it's worth a look.

- [Nikon D40 Flash Fix](http://vimeo.com/3141400)
- [D700 DIY Fix](http://jorgesantosphoto.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/d700_popupflash_diy_repair1.pdf)

If you don't mind spending some extra cash you could possibly get an external flash unit (if you don't already have one) for your model. Pros of doing so would be getting more power from your flash, ETTL, swiveling flash head, possibility of off camera flash.

A little searching also revealed this could be a particularly dangerous [endeavor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11463/how-can-i-fix-the-flash-in-a-nikon-d80-camera). So the other option to consider would be also to bring it back to Nikon for servicing.

Comment: The very high voltage capacitor in all flashes can kill you. And it remains charged for a very long time after you turn the flash off. Do not attempt this unless you are experienced in electronic repair.