# nikon d3100 built in flash not working

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, nikon-d3100

I’ve been using my D3100 for awhile now. Today I took a few pictures using the flash and everything worked fine. After that I spent some time exploring menu set-up options and played with a few settings. Since then I have observed that my flash isn’t working. It pops-up properly under low light but doesn't produce any light. I went to menu setup and reset all the options but still flash doesn’t flash at all.  However, it pops up properly. Any suggestion on if I need to do anything or is going to the service center the only option now?

Comment: Which settings, specifically, did you play with?

Comment: personally i cant imagine that any setting affected this phenomenon.
i think you should take it to the service.

Comment: The answer to these questions are 1. Reset to default 2. Take to repair shop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if the built-in flash on my dSLR is broken beyond self-repair?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/how-can-i-tell-if-the-built-in-flash-on-my-dslr-is-broken-beyond-self-repair)

Comment: There are two different reset options for the D3100, one under the *Shooting* menu and one under the *Setup* menu. Be sure to do both. Also be sure your battery is fully charged. It may just be taking longer than expected to charge the capacitors for the flash if you battery is almost exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, looks likes you'll have to take it in. Try calling your near by Nikon service centre, and getting someone at the service desk, they usually can give you a an idea of if you need to bring it in.

If it isn't working after resetting, or not even firing in dark areas under full auto mode it probably needs repair :(

Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUrV8rGxVEY) that shows what hardware problems could prevent it. I know it's a D40, but same principal. I don't suggest you open it up, got zapped plenty of times :)

Answer (score 0):

If the flash is not blown, it most likely is wiring/innards that are not connected properly. To fix this you simply need to take apart the camera, locate and reattach said part — or take it to a shop.